# Python Selenium: Why am I getting Error 404?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

Can someone please explain why I am getting an error 404 and if there is a way to work around this? when I put this link : https://www.lowes.com/pl/Drywall-joint-compound-Drywall-Building-supplies/4294858286?refinement=1 into my web browser it seems to work fine. But when I run my code below the page seems to pop up for a second and then it gives me an error 404. I would like to scrape the contents of this page eventually so any help is greatly appreciated. Here is the code I am running:

```
import undetected_chromedriver as uc

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import pandas as pd
import time
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

options = Options()
driver = uc.Chrome()

website = 'https://www.lowes.com/pl/Drywall-joint-compound-Drywall-Building-supplies/4294858286?refinement=1'
driver.get(website)

for _ in range(4):
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0, 2000);")
    time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: Trying to access the referred page gives me access denied

Comment: @LucasMouraGomes when you use this link and then click availability->out of stock does the same thing happen? https://www.lowes.com/pl/Drywall-joint-compound-Drywall-Building-supplies/4294858286

Comment: that link also shows access denied

Comment: can you give the full error stack? and the version of selenium

Comment: I'm going to guess that Lowes did, in fact, detect the "undetected" chromedriver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below code, which doesn't give me an error:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
url = 'https://www.lowes.com/pl/Drywall-joint-compound-Drywall-Building-supplies/4294858286?refinement=1'
driver.get(url)
```

In my case `selenium.__version__ =='4.12.0'`

Comment: i am on selenium 4.8.2 when I run that code it still appears but  I can no longer see the prices because they are location locked. which is why I was using undetected chrome driver